# Is "mela" somehow related to "melanzana"?

Tags: etymology

"Mela" means apple, and "melanzana" means "eggplant."

I note in this context, that "manzana," which seems like a "cross" between mela and melanzana means "apple," in Spanish, a closely related Romance language.

And the French use "pomme de terre," that is "apple of the earth" as their description of potato.

On the other hand, "eggplant" is translated "aubergine" in French and "berenjena" "in Spanish. So I would expect the translation to be an Italian equivalent, something like "berengina." Except that it is not.

Here is a [dictionary](http://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/melanzana) link that gives the definition, but makes no mention of apple.

So is there a context where "eggplant" is reasonably translated (in a non-English language) as "apple plant?" And is this actually the case in Italian?

Comment: Have you considered checking any dictionary? In the SE websites, one is expected to show «any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem» (http://italian.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error), while this question can be answered by simply opening any dictionary at the entry *melanzana*.

Comment: http://www.lastampa.it/2014/07/06/cronaca/rubriche/saper-spendere/storia-della-melanzana-una-mela-non-sana-6mJkUWzh21CJCeLBYSrdKP/pagina.html

Comment: @DaG: First, this is an etymology question, not a dictionary question. Second, I showed my research by relating the question to words I do know,, even thought they were in other Romance languages. So the real question, is, "I've noticed a pattern in other "Latin" languages: does it apply to Italian since they all have common Latin roots.

Comment: As you might have noticed, most dictionaries, including several of those listed in our [reference works](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/a/123/37) section do give the etymology of each word. “Background research” means “I have found this and this here and here, but they contradict each other/they don't seem convincing/whatever for this and this reason”, not “I would expect so and so”.

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manzana

Comment: @DaG: And I just added the first dictionary link that I looked up, and I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Ok, now you have lots of links to actual dictionaries, not any old website of dubious value. Have you found what you looked for?

Comment: @DaG: Nor could I find it in word reference, which was on the list suggested by you.http://www.wordreference.com/iten/melanzana Have I done enough research for you to remove your downvote? The fact of the matter was that I had earlier "checked references," even though they were of dubious value, as you said.

Comment: You'll have done a modicum of research when you'll have browsed some *actual dictionary* (Treccani, De Mauro...; even obsolete Pianigiani gives an acceptable answer).

Comment: @Charo: Your Mirriam Webster link technically answers my question, but your stampa article was much better.

Comment: @DaG: The problem is up to which point we can expect from a beginner to use dictionaries that are Italian only. The OP has opened a [debate about this on Meta](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/q/1272) which is also interesting for me because I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/melanzana), the word "melanzana" comes from Arabic "bādingiān" crossed with "mela". This is explained with some more detail in this [La Stampa article](http://www.lastampa.it/2014/07/06/cronaca/rubriche/saper-spendere/storia-della-melanzana-una-mela-non-sana-6mJkUWzh21CJCeLBYSrdKP/pagina.html). Latin word "mālum" means fruit and from this was derived the word "mela" or "melo" which, in the Middle Ages, was used to construct the name of some fruits: "melagrana", "melacotogna", "melangolo", "melone". In particular,  "mela-bādingiān" gave rise to the word "melanzana".

According to [Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manzana), the Spanish word "manzana" comes from from Old Spanish "mazana" or "maçana", that derives from latin "māla Matiana", which comes from the name of [Gaius Matius](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaius_Matius), a 1st century b.c. Roman writer on gastronomy.

A Catalan word for "eggplant" is "albergínia". According to [Gran Diccionari de la llengua catalana](http://www.enciclopedia.cat/EC-GDLC-e00005230.xml) this word also comes from Arabic "al-bādingiān" (note that "al" is the Arabic article). And according to [this source](http://languagehat.com/the-multifarious-aubergine/) and [this other one](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=aubergine), the Catalan term is at the origin of French and English "aubergine".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76126/discussion-on-answer-by-charo-is-mela-somehow-related-to-melanzana).

Answer (score 0):

Look at  the web version of the *Vocabolario Etimologico della Lingua Italiana* by  Ottorino Pianigiani.

For Melanzana see at: http://www.etimo.it/?term=melanzana&find=Cerca

[image]

EDIT rough translation:

french mérangène, mélongène; [from late latin belangolus, merangolus]: from spanish BERENGÉNA [which has been considered close to MÉLA by false etymology], the latter from arab BADINDGIAN

[[second paragraph, a botanical description of eggplants ... *called Melongèna Arabum*]]

Comment: This piece is entirely in Italian, without further English commentary from you, which is to say that it is "too advanced" for a rank beginner like me.

Comment: However according to [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/melanzana/)  and to La Stampa article linked in my previous comment, it comes from Arabic "bādingiān" crossed with "mela" or "melo", that comes from Latin "mālum" which means fruit.

Comment: It may be interesting to remark that the wiktionary claims that the Arabic *al-bādingiān* is also the origin of the Catalan *albergínia* and, from there, to the French and English *aubergine*. I was unable to find a more reliable source but it seems very plausible to me.

Comment: @DenisNardin: The [Gran Diccionari de la llengua catalana](http://www.enciclopedia.cat/EC-GDLC-e00005230.xml) confirms this etymology for the Catalan word. The origin of French and English terms is also mentioned [here](http://languagehat.com/the-multifarious-aubergine/) and [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=aubergine).

Comment: @DenisNardin: By the way, the Arabic "al" is the article.

Comment: @charo, all. La Stampa article you linked sounds unreliable when it claims that _Nel Medioevo aggiungevano il prefisso “melo” per indicare vegetali provenienti da lontano_. Do you know about "melo" as a prefix? Also, _melanzana_ as _“mela non sana”_ seems just wrong.

Comment: @mario: Penso che "mela non sana" non faccia riferimento all'etimologia, ma a qualche credenza popolare.

Comment: @charo, I agree on the last point, thanks

Comment: @mario: As far as I know, Latin word "mālum" means fruit and from this was derived the word "mela" or "melo" which, in the Middle Ages, was used to construct the name of some fruits: "melagrana", "melacotogna", "melangolo", "melone". I think this is the sense of what it's explained in La Stampa article.

Comment: @charo, see the point now. Maybe! (I just discovered what a [melangolo](http://www.curiosandoingiardino.it/blog/larancio-selvatico-detto-anche-melangolo-o-merangola/) is, and it seems a nice fruit. I am looking for a bottle of _Liquore di Merangola_ :-)

Comment: @Charo: So the Italians used a fruit to describe a vegetable, just like the French did with pomme and pomme de terre. Or maybe "eggplant" is a hybrid "fruit-vegetable" like a "tomato."

Comment: @TomAu:  The part of the plant which is edible is the fruit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggplant.